# How do I view a migrated question on the site that it was migrated from?

Tags: support, questions, migration, faq-proposed

I'd like to view a question that's been migrated to another site in the Stack Exchange network. However, I would like to view the question on the original site it was posted on.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 13):

You can add `?noredirect=1` to the end of the migrated question's URL to view the non-migrated copy (as long as it hasn't been deleted).

This also works for questions without answers closed as duplicates on sites which you don't have an account.